# A plugin, which allows editing certain template regions

Tags: plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What methods to use to create small, editable pieces of text for static pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26110/what-methods-to-use-to-create-small-editable-pieces-of-text-for-static-pages)

I'm looking for a plugin, which would allow editing of certain predefined template regions.

For example: I define that footer text is editable and administrator is able to edit just that, without touching code in template editor.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26110/what-methods-to-use-to-create-small-editable-pieces-of-text-for-static-pages/26114#26114

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wyck](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1509/wyck) pointed me to this answer: [What methods to use to create small, editable pieces of text for static pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26110/what-methods-to-use-to-create-small-editable-pieces-of-text-for-static-pages/26114#26114). And WP-Blocks was exactly what I needed after a few compatibility fixes :)

Answer (score 0):

This is standard WP functionality and can be accomplished without a plugin.

1. Using the admin area, create a page called `Footer`.
2. in you theme's footer.php file, add the following code inside the main footer `<div>`.

   ```
   <?php
   $query  = new WP_Query(array('pagename'=>'footer'));
   while ( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
     the_content();
   endwhile;
   ?>
   ```
3. Now any text in the footer 'page' will appear there in your theme.

It would be possible to make the interface clearer with a custom post type, but this is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: This would quickly get very busy as I'm going to add quite a few of those.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply adding a widget area? Textwidgets are easily editable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a plugin, but if you're capable of building it into the theme yourself check this out: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/

I've used this tutorial with success.  Specifically, the "Footer Copyright Text" option should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at [Page.ly MultiEdit](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagely-multiedit/) plugin?

> One thing I always wished WP would do better is allow for multiple
>   editable content blocks on page templates. This plugin uses custom
>   fields to create simple tinyMCE editable regions on page templates.