# Need help finding the right plugin for a dynamic piece of content that appears multiple places

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to find the perfect plugin for what I need to do. I have a blog that has posts about games. each post will have a category that assigns it to its game (although it could have another related field if need be). I need to have a block of HTML that appears at the bottom of all posts that are in the same category (think "where to buy this game" links) that should be entered only once. Ideally, they could edit this HTML or the content for this HTML in the admin, but I'll take what I can get.

Anything come to mind?

Comment: Related, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26110/what-methods-to-use-to-create-small-editable-pieces-of-text-for-static-pages/26114#26114

Comment: close! my content blocks need to be different and dynamic, yet appear on the same template. So on my post detail page, it needs to bring in some content that is similar to posts of this type, or category, if associated with that post. Typical relational db thang....

Comment: The use the default `WP Query` and custom post types.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just putting HTML content into the category description and shoving the description in the page.